# Self-Binding with Castle Windsor in C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ninject

With the Ninject Dependency Injection Container, I can perform self-binding in a manner similar to the following:

```
MyClass mc = ninjectKernel.Get<MyClass>();
```

Is there an equivalent sort of operation in Castle Windsor?

Comment: I'm unsure what feature you're referring to, but Windsor's `MyClass mc = container.Resolve<MyClass>();` would on the surface seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Doh, obvious. Thanks. That looks suspiciosly like an answer to me if you want to post it. To get it to work I had to register it against itself. `container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>());`

Comment: @JamesWiseman if I recall correctly, you can save yourself a little typing: `container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>());` when the "for" type argument is a class, and there's no "implemented by" call, Windsor is smart enough to register the class as the implementer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Castle Windsor's corresponding call is (unless I'm missing some intricate functionality in NInject)

```
MyClass mc = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

and, as you point out in the comments, you'll need to register the class against itself to work in Windsor.

Comment: In order to avoid having to register each individual class against itself, you can register multiple classes in some assembly against themselves, based on their base class.  For example, I use the following to self-register all my MVC Controller-derived classes:
`container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Controller>().WithServiceSelf());`

Answer (score 3):

In accordance with  Joachim Isaksson comments, this is what I had to do:

In the installer:

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyClass>().ImplementedBy<MyClass>());
```

To resolve:

```
MyClass mc = container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

Comment: You don't need the `.ImplementedBy<MyClass>()`.  You can just have the `.For<MyClass>()` and it will work.